# Would it be possible to share some memory with GNU Parallel?

Tags: shared-memory, gnu-parallel

Imagine that you use gnu parallel to run several script that load every time a big object in memory, like a corpus of document for example. In the case of a read only acces to this object the question is:

Can I load this object once in memory and share the read access by all the process running under Gnu Parallel ?

Comment: Would using `/dev/shm` help here?

Comment: If you can load the object using mmap, then it ought to work. In other words: It depends more on the worker scripts than on GNU Parallel.

Comment: So it means to the workers should try to acess an existing thread for example ?

Comment: Or maybe some IPC (systemV) methods. Any preference ?