# Is it possible to share a costly object between multiple Gnu Parallel processes?

Tags: parallel-processing, nlp, multiprocessing, gnu, spacy

I am loading a spacy dictionary for the purposes of lemmatizing multiple documents. I am using Gnu Parallel to use my lemmatization script on multiple documents (over 1000 documents) to speed the lemmatization up. However loading the spacy dictionary is a very costly step, which I would ideally like to load once and share across all the processes. Below is the dictionary I am loading.

The following questions ask similar to what I am asking, but there are no conclusive answers.

[Sharing shared object between multiple processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618543/sharing-shared-object-between-multiple-processes)

[Would it be possible to share some memory with GNU Parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933830/would-it-be-possible-to-share-some-memory-with-gnu-parallel)

```
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner'])
```

```
ls -d -1 /home/ndg/arc/reddit/2015/RC_2015-[0][1-5]*.gz | parallel -j20 --pipe parallel -j100 --no-notice python lemmatize_subreddit_posts.py
```

Comment: The simple answer is no.

Comment: @amirouche thanks. i guess that saves time to from looking for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: If the goal is not to save memory, then it might make sense to load the dictionary, pickle it and save the pickled version, which can than be loaded by others. Pickled versions ought to be fast at loading.